# How to build custom FreeBSD os Image for Raspberry Pi using Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, raspberry-pi, freebsd

I want to build FreeBSD Image for Raspberry Pi Image using Ubuntu OS if it is not possible help me out of it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it displays a complete lack of research on the topic, when instead several online sites exist which provide information about exactly this argument.

Answer (score 1):

A [quick look](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/crossbuild) into the freeBSD wiki would have saved you a bit of reputation...